# Is there shortcut to switch between visible windows (apps) within current desktop?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager

I have 3+ windows (different apps) placed on a single desktop. Also i have bunch of other desktops with other windows-setups.

How do i toggle focus between visible windows of current desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts in this area you can set the following keyboard shortcuts to achieve the toggle focus between windows on your current desktop. Please see this screenshot for further instructions. I use macOS 10.12.2 (Sierra) on a late 2015 Macbook Pro 15.

[image: macOS 10.12.2 (Sierra)]

Comment: Which of these commands allows one to toggle between the windows (different apps too) in the current desktop? For example, I like to have a terminal and pdf documentation open in a desktop. I would like to be able to go back and forth between the two quickly. I can almost get there with "Move focus to active of next window," but that seems to only go one direction (i.e., terminal to doc reader) and then I can't switch back immediately to the previous window.